# Kafka Streams Topology which inserts records to DynamoDB Model - Consumption rate is low

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb, apache-kafka-streams

This issue has been eating my head for few days now & have come here for getting some help on figuring out the root cause. Let me elaborate the whole issue.

**Problem Statement**

I have a KafkaStreams topology which reads JSON strings from a kafka topic. There is a processor which gets these messages & inserts into DynamoDB using AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient. Thats pretty much the topology does.

**More Details**

Source kafka topic has 200 partitions. Kafka Streams Topology is configured with 50 Stream threads currently (we previously had set 10,20,30,100,200 as values with no luck)

**Issue Being Faced**

We are visualizing the lag in kafka topic along with the consumption rate (per minute) in Grafana dashboard. What we see is that, after the Streams process is started there is a steady consumption rate of 300K to 500K Messages per minute for around 5 to 6 mins. After that, the rate drops steeply and stays fixed at 63K per minute. It doesn't go up or down & fixed right at 63K messages per minute.

**Parameters configured**

1. Poll_ms - 10000 (10 secs)
2. Max_Poll_Records - 10000
3. Max.Partition.Fetch.bytes - 50 MB
4. commit_ms - 15000 (15 secs)
5. kafka.consumer.heartbeat.interval - 60 secs
6. session.timeout.ms - 180000 (3 minutes)
7. partition.assignment.strategy - org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor

AmazonAsyncClient Connection Pool Size - 200 (to match the no. of topic partitions)

**DynamoDB Model**

We even saw the metrics on the corresponding DynamoDB table & we saw throttling for 10 or 15 secs after which autoscaling kicked in. We saw no capacity issues/errors on Cloudwatch.

Please let me know you more details are needed or if problem statement is unclear. Appreciate the help.

**Threaddumps**

We checked the threaddumps for any clues. We only see 200 consumer threads on "WAITING" state for polling & there was no threads on BLOCKED state.

Comment: In general, Kafka Streams isn't meant to be used with external systems. That's what Kafka Connect is for

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Agreed.. If am not wrong there are licensing costs involved with it if thats gonna be used across several broker nodes.. I agree, thats the best way to do this  but whats being done isn't wrong either right.

Comment: Kafka Connect is open source, there is no licensing for it. I'm not sure there is an existing Dynamo Sink connector, but my point was that you could use that AsyncClient in a Connect Task rather than embedding within a Streams job

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. I see this verbiage in every Confluent connector page (DynamoDB connector, etc).

License
You can use this connector for a 30-day trial period without a license key.

After 30 days, this connector is available under a Confluent enterprise license. Confluent issues Confluent enterprise license keys to subscribers, along with providing enterprise-level support for Confluent Platform and your connectors. If you are a subscriber, please contact Confluent Support at support@confluent.io for more information. See Confluent Platform license for license properties.

Comment: Sure... But that doesn't prevent you from writing your own connect task like you've done similarly in kstreams